How to produce a better visualization for a graph in R
install.packages("ggplot2") 
install.packages("tidyr") 
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidyr) 

data <- data.frame(Time = c('2014', '2017'), setor = c('MI2','MI3','MI4','MI5','MI6','MI7','MI8','MI9','MI10','MI11','MI12','MI13','MI14','MI15','MI16','MI17','MI18','MI19','MI20','MI21','MI22','MI23','MI24','MI25','MI26','MI27','MI28','MI29','MI30','MI31','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9','N10','N11','N12','N13','N14','N15','N16','N17','N18','N19','N20','N21','N22','N23','N24','N25','N26','N27','N28','N29','N30','N31'), 
Group1_Rank_2014 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,4,4,1,1,1,1,5,2,4,4,2,4,4,2,4,2,1,4,4,2,2,1,2,4,2,4,1), 
Group2_Rank_2017 = (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,1,2,2,1,3,2,1,5,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1)) 

data_long <- pivot_longer(data, cols = starts_with("Group"), names_to = "Group", values_to = "Rank") 

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Time, y = Rank, color = "black", group = interaction(setor, Group))) + geom_line(aes(linetype = setor)) + 
 + geom_point() + labs(x = "Time", y = "Ranking", title = "Mudança de Ranking dos Setores de 2014 a 2017") + scale_y_reverse() +
   theme_minimal() + theme())

This code doesn't produce a line to show a change between 2014 and 2017 (the result is presented in the image). But, I need 60 lines going from position 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 in 2014 to position 1, 2, 3 ,4 or 5 in 2017. How can I make it? What I need: To have a graph with lines representing 60 sectors going from  position 1,2,3,4 or 5 in 2014 to 1,2,3,4 or 5 in 2017 (axis X must be just 2014 and 2017)

Does the original Time column mean anything? you seem to have separate columns for 2014 and 2017, but each group only has one value of the Time column. But with those 60 rows, you only have 8 distinct combos dplyr::distinct(data, Group1_Rank_2014, Group2_Rank_2017). That means nearly all the lines will directly overlap which make it hard to see what's going on.

I don't see a way to properly show all those in a single chart because there is so much overlap, but here are two ways you might approach it: direct labeling with ggrepl to pull the labels apart or jittering geom_textpath:
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(geomtextpath)

data <- data.frame(
  sector = c('MI2','MI3','MI4','MI5','MI6','MI7','MI8','MI9','MI10','MI11','MI12','MI13','MI14','MI15','MI16','MI17','MI18','MI19','MI20','MI21','MI22','MI23','MI24','MI25','MI26','MI27','MI28','MI29','MI30','MI31','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9','N10','N11','N12','N13','N14','N15','N16','N17','N18','N19','N20','N21','N22','N23','N24','N25','N26','N27','N28','N29','N30','N31'),
  group1_rank_2014 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,4,4,1,1,1,1,5,2,4,4,2,4,4,2,4,2,1,4,4,2,2,1,2,4,2,4,1), 
  group2_rank_2017 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,4,1,2,2,1,3,2,1,5,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1)
  ) 

data_long <- pivot_longer(
  data %>% filter(group1_rank_2014 != group2_rank_2017), 
  cols = starts_with("group"), 
  names_to = "group", 
  values_to = "rank") %>% 
  mutate(time = substr(group, nchar(group) - 3, nchar(group)),
         time = factor(time, levels = c("2014", "2017"))
  )

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = time, y = rank)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(group = sector), 
    ) +
  geom_text_repel(data = data_long %>% filter(time == "2014"), 
            aes(label = sector, x = "2014", y = rank), hjust = 1, size = 3,
            max.overlaps = Inf, direction = "y", min.segment.length = 10,
            force = 1.5
  ) +
  geom_text_repel(data = data_long %>% filter(time == "2017"), 
            aes(label = sector, x = "2017", y = rank), hjust = 0, size = 3,
            max.overlaps = Inf, direction = "y", min.segment.length = 10,
            force = 1.5
  ) +
  theme_minimal()



ggplot(data_long, aes(x = time, y = rank)) +
  geom_textpath(
    aes(group = sector, label = sector), 
    size = 3,
    position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = 0.2, seed = 1)
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

